# Plugin that figures where an artifact was downloaded by Maven

Tags: java, maven

Was wondering if there is a plugin that can tell me which repository was an artifact downloaded from by Maven? I believe the M2E plugin doesn't do that. I understand that by running the "mvn project-info-reports:dependencies" is a way to generate a report that gives these details.

Comment: You mean a plugin that will inspect the _maven.repositories files inside your local repository?